# Problem with Jenkins plugins when moving to a new computer

Tags: jenkins

After moving Jenkins to a new computer I cannot upgrade plugins since it thinks the new version is older than the installer.

1. I get the following message:

Some plugins could not be loaded due to unsatisfied dependencies. Fix these issues and restart Jenkins to re-enable these plugins.
Dependency errors:
Static Analysis Utilities (1.96)
Update required: Maven Integration plugin (2.12.1) to be updated to 2.17 or higher
Update required: Matrix Project Plugin (1.6) to be updated to 1.7.1 or higher
Update required: OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin (1.3) to be updated to 1.5 or higher

and several more.

2. I then try to upgarde Maven INtegration polugin (and alla others) it looks like the are installed and Jenkins is restarted. But I get the same error again.
3. When looking in the plugin folder I see that I have several version of the plugin. I try to remove the different folders and then detect that the old verision is still used even if the new version is available in the folder.
4. In the pluginmanager/installed the Maven Integration plugin is listed as version 2.12.1 and the possibility to DOWNGRADE to 3.8. 3.8 is the version that I upgrade to.

My conclusion is that during the move of the .jenkins folder to the new computer the dates of the old plugins are getting new values which confuses Jenkins. Is that a correct conclusion? How can I correct it?

Comment: Zip/unzip should solve the date problem, but seems you did not copy "something"

Answer (score 0):

Since the folder dates were changed long ago at the old computer I was not able to zip the old .jenkins folder with "correct" dates

However, I found a way forward anyway. I did like this:

1. Started with a newly installed Jenkins version.
2. Made sure I had all necessary plugins in the new Jenkins installation
3. Copied the following folders from the old computers .jenkins zip file:

- jobs
- nodes
- secrets
- users
- workspace

4. Then I also moved the files in the .jenkins folder